# Set of points with a deviation from the main route javascript

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, point

Here I have image with MAIN ROUTE from POINT A (lat,lng) to POINT B(lat,lng)

Also I have object(points) and I want to know is it posible to get all objects which is far from main road 5km, so like on image here.

[image]

Or how I can calculate that using google map api. Any idea? Is it posible with polilines service or so ...

sorry for my english

Comment: The [RouteBoxer utility](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html) might meet your needs (not quite as precise as your specification)

Comment: is there some more examples, on site i only see one

Comment: also how many request I need to send here for route of etc. 200mi :), becouse I only have 1000 request for google place library?

Comment: This [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-maps-api-3]+RouteBoxer) should provide you with a couple of other examples.

Comment: yes, but please  shoe some of your example for this code...